# How to make Unity gameobject variables only editable from inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to assign public GameObject from editor inspector, but disallowing reassigning via script. How can this be achieved?

Comment: If you assign a variable via the inspector even if you change it in the script it doesn't get changed anyway. So the feature you want to implement already exists.

Comment: @MathewHD that is not true! You can simply overwrite the value e.g. in `Start` => value is changed ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it private but Serializable:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject whatever;
```

This way it will show up in the inspector but code from other classes can't reach it. Nothing is stopping you from changing the value from inside your own class though.